# dreamhost vps nodejs and mongodb wont start

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb

I have found a lot on the nodejs however it is all how people can install node without a vps. I have a vps and I have node installed. I am able to start my node server with npm start or node app.js however it appears to be listening to localhost still because when I visit the domain the console does not receive a request and I get a Passenger error saying the application cannot be started even though my ssh terminal says it is.

passenger says to start a node server I should upload it and create a tmp directory and touch the restart.txt inside it. but this has no effect. they also go on to say to run the node in passenger standalone mode I should use

```
passenger start //this returns passenger command not found
```

so how do I start a node server to handle the backend of a domain?

then my second issue is mongodb. according to dreamhost support everything I need to know about using mongodb from their vps is located on http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MongoDB#MongoDB_on_Dreamhost however all this says is to go to server configuration panel and activate mongodb and your done.

I have done that and I am unable to use the shell commands, mongo or mongod.

I started a support chat with them and the guy continually sent the the previous link as if I was missing a huge portion of information on it. I have read it ten times it does not provide the necessary information to access via the shell.

The reason I am bringing up both of these issues together is because I think they are related. the passenger error page lists mongodb error about invalid elf headers and not being able to load the c++ drivers. I am sorry if I am missing something very simple but I cannot figure this out. like I said before when I google these issues I find a few unresolved posts and a bunch of posts from people who are trying to install these services on a shared hosting plan.

For detailed passenger error visit: http://flamingoflea.net

Comment: I don't know about Dreamhost but it was dead-easy to set up Node on Digital Ocean, especially given VPS-specific tutorials like [How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04). Sorry I can't give help specific to Dreamhost.

Comment: I have narrowed it down a bit. the issue is an authentication issue dreamhost starts mongodb with the --auth command before I had the chance to create users